# Closed form on the $2$-sphere

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, differential-forms, stokes-theorem

I'm wondering about something which should be trivial. 
Suppose we look at the $S^2$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$, with the volume form $\omega = \sin \phi \,d\phi \,d \theta$.

We know that  $\int_{S^2}\omega = 4\pi$. But on the other hand $\omega$ seems to be a closed form, so the integral should be zero as $S^2$ is the boundary of $D^3$, the $3$ dimensional ball with radius $1$.

Where do I make a mistake in my reasoning?

Comment: The form $\omega$ is a volume form hence closed as it is of top degree. But $\mathrm d\omega$ is the zero form on $S^2$. In order to apply Stokes' theorem you need to work with a form that is defined on all of $D^3$. EDIT: Look at the answer by Slup which explains it in a much better way.

Comment: Note, by the way, that this is only a volume form away from the north and south poles (where the coordinate system breaks down, anyway). But in different coordinates one can check that it's fine at those points too.

Answer (score 1):

First, the issue is not related to extending forms from the boundary to the whole manifold.

**Proposition**:  Suppose $M^n$ is a manifold with boundary $\partial M$.  Then any smooth $k$-form on $\partial M$ has a smooth extension to all of $M$.

**Proof**:  By the [collar neighborhood theorem](http://www.math.toronto.edu/vtk/1300Fall2015/lecture-nov2.pdf), there is a neighborhood $U$ of $\partial M$ for which $U\cong \partial M\times [0,1)$ with the diffeomorphism taking $\partial M$ to $\partial M \times \{0\}$.

Let $\phi:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a $C^\infty$ function with $\phi(0) = 1$ and $\phi(x) = 0$ for $x\in [1/2,1]$.  For example, one can use $$\phi(x) = \begin{cases} e^{- \frac{1}{1-4x^2} + 1} & x\in (-1/2,1/2)\\ 0 & x\notin (-1/2,1/2)\end{cases}.$$  Then we can extend $\omega$ to $U \cong \partial M \times [0,1)$ by the formula $\omega_{m,x} = \phi(x)\omega_m$, where I am thinking of $m\in \partial M$.

Then we simply define $\omega$ on $M\setminus U$ by declaring it to be identically zero. Because $\omega_{u,x}$ is identically $0$ for any $x \geq 1/2$, this is a smooth extension.$\square$

$ \ $

However, if the form $\omega$ is closed, there is no reason why the extension should be closed.  Using the $\phi$ above, if $\omega$ is closed, then on $U$ we have $d(\omega_{m,x}) = d\phi(x)\omega_m = (d\phi) \wedge \omega_m$.  On $(-1/2, 1/2)$, this is non-zero, unless $\omega_m = 0$.

Further, Stokes's theorem actually guarantees that some closed forms don't have extensions to closed forms.  In your example, $\omega$ *can* be extended to all of $D^3$, but if $d\omega = 0$ on all of $D^3$ then Stokes's theorem gives you a contradiction as you noted.